# How to process long JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

```
var fs = require("fs")
var https = require("https")

var request = require('request')
var username = 'u'
var password = 'p'
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.website.com/longList'
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.dir(err)
    return
  }

  var data = JSON.parse(body)
  fs.appendFile("A.txt", body , "utf8", function(){})
```

**A.txt contains whole response**

but when I try to itterate through response, I can't write all the names contained in the response into the file -->

```
  data["data"].forEach(function(bar){
    fs.appendFile("B.txt", bar.name + " " , "utf8", function(){})
    count ++
  })
 })
```

**B.txt contains only first 2044 names**

Why is this happening and how to write all names into the file?

Comment: What would be `data["data"].length`? Any chance an error happened that you ignored?

Comment: @zerkms No, in original file, there is a count variable which shows it is iterated 8k times.

Comment: So can you please answer my both questions?

Comment: @zerkms I just tested  it - 8164. Second question: it is simple program, you basicaly see whole program.

Comment: So, if the length is 8164 - it should have written 8164 entries. Please use the 4th argument of `fs.appendFile` to check if there were any errors.

Comment: @zerkms When I console.log bar.name inside callback function, in only logs those first 2k names. Is that what you meant with checking for errors in 4th arguement?